# From a string of comma-delimited phrases, get the first word from each phrase

Tags: php, string, text-extraction, delimited

I have a string, for example:

> "abc b, bcd vr, cd deb"

I would like to take the first word of this string until every single point in this case would result in "abc bcd cd". My code unfortunately does not work. Can you help me?

```
$string = "abc b, bcd vr, cd deb";
$ay = explode(",", $string);
$num = count($ay); 
$ii = 0;
while ($ii != $num) {
    $first = explode(" ", $ay[$ii]);
    echo $first[$ii];
    $ii = $ii+1;
}
```

Comment: Try using regular expressions.

Comment: What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function get_first_word($string)
{
    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    return $words[0];
}

$string = 'abc b, bcd vr, cd deb';
$splitted = explode(', ', $string);
$new_splitted = array_map('get_first_word', $splitted);

var_dump($new_splitted);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string= "abc b, bcd vr, cd deb";
$ay = explode(",", $string);
$num= count($ay); 
$ii= 0;
while ($ii!=$num){
$first = explode(" ", $ay[$ii]);
echo ($ii == 0) ? $first[0] . " " : $first[1] . " ";
$ii= $ii+1;
} 
?>
```

You should only take `$first[$ii]` when you get first element becouse `explode` take this whan is before space at first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string= "abc b, bcd vr, cd deb";
$ay = explode(",", $string);
foreach($ay as $words) {
    $words = explode(' ', $words);
    echo $words[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$newString = array_reduce(
    // split string on every ', '
    explode(", ", $string), 
    // add the first word of every comma section to the partial string  
    function(&$result, $item){

        $result .= array_shift(explode(" ", $item)) . " ";

        return $result;

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid exploding and looping by writing a regular expression and just imploding the matches.  Match the non-whitespace characters which immediately follow the start of the string or a comma then space.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/olius))

```
$text = 'abc b, bcd vr, cd deb';
preg_match_all('/(?:^|, )\K\S+/', $text, $m);
echo implode(' ', $m[0] ?? []);
```

Output:

```
abc bcd cd
```